# Other ways to say "I'm rooting for you?"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

What are other ways one can say that have the same meaning as, "I'm rooting for you?"

Comment: This question seems like a poll style question: -1

Comment: In Australia and New Zealand, you could say "I'm having sex for you". That's what rooting means there.

Comment: I'm leafing/stemming/flowering/blooming/pining for you.

Comment: There are lots of ways to express what amounts to sporting solidarity with a team or individual: "Go Phillies!" "Up Wigan!" "I'll be cheerleading for you!" "I'm your biggest fan!" "I bleed [team's] [main uniform colors]!" "I'm with you all the way!" "You can count on me to be in your corner!" "I'm on your side—with a megaphone!" "Win or lose, you're the best!" "Stand tall and I'll stand with you!" "I know you can do it!" "You've got backup!" "I'll always be on your side!" "When it comes to you, I'm loyal—and loud!" "I'm a true believer!" etc. etc. How many different ways does the OP need?

Comment: On the "This question has not received enough attention" front, I have to wonder whether FumbleFingers is not making an ironical allusion to the almost 50,000 views that this question has received. Also, how is the question not a request for a **list** of alternative ways to say the stated phrase? And what evidence is there of any preliminary research by the poster prior to asking the question?

Comment: "Go, maan (gaal) Go!"

Comment: I am honestly surprised this question is open, given ELU's standards.

Comment: I can't help feeling that, since this was asked in Aug 2011, the person you were rooting for has probably finished doing whatever it was by now.

Comment: If @JohnLawler and Optimal Cynic are both right, then that suggests it can mean either *I'm flowering for you* or *I'm deflowering for you*. Isn't it nice how language works?

Comment: @SvenYargs Probably the reason that the dupe got reopen votes, is voters thought a more useful answer might be appropriate for the OP's very specific need: *I have a niece who has cancer and is waiting for more results, she also has to have a painful operation to remove the cancer. I'm sending her and have sent her cards, "thinking of you" I want to say I'm rooting for her but wish that I could find a better way to say it. Any suggestions ? ( I'm not a Christian )* I'm not sure given that very specific background that most of the answers on here were going to help that poster much ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some other ways:

- I'm supporting you.
- I'm pulling for you.
- I'll cheer for you.
- I'll barrack for you (Australian).

Comment: "Ganbare" (gahn-bah-ray) in Japanese!

Answer (score 9):

> NOTE: I've just seen the (recent) duplicate of this question, which seems to have been the motivation for putting a bounty on this question. My answer attempts to cover all the most plausible scenarios in which one might use the phrase, but in the context of the other question, it is the third section that's most relevant here.

I think it depends a lot on the context, and in particular whether the speaker is in a position to exert some influence the outcome, or only to hope for the best.

#### In a position to influence the outcome

If you were heading into a meeting where someone was going to be selected for a job, for instance, and you were going to be part of the discussion, you might say

> I'm right behind you

or

> You've got my vote

or

> I've got your back

#### Spectator

If you'll be avidly watching but can't hope to have any significant influence (e.g., sports) then you might try

> I'll be with you every step of the way

(perhaps a careless promise if it's a marathon...) or

> I'll be cheering you on

#### Away from the action

If you can't even watch, but want to offer what moral support you can, the language again changes. Suppose you were sending someone in for a heart bypass; you could say

> I'll be thinking of you

or

> You're in my thoughts and prayers

or (if you want to get really sentimental and maybe even slightly creepy)

> I'll be holding you in my heart

#### Conclusion

I've heard *I'm rooting for you* used in *all* these contexts. The point is that it's really a vague expression of some kind of unspecified support, and so how it gets cashed out will depend on the nature of the support you can offer.

(There are other meanings, of course. No one has yet mentioned *I'm [trying to drink your breastmilk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_reflexes#Rooting_reflex)* or *I'm [getting low-level access to your phone for you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_%28Android_OS%29)*.)

Comment: Someone who is falling, "I'll catch you"

Answer (score 2):

"I'm rooting for you", in this context, *root* would be defined as follows:

> root /rut or, sometimes, rʊt/ [objectless verb] (1) to encourage a team or contestant by cheering or applauding enthusiastically (2) to lend moral support. Origin: 1885-90, Americanism; perhaps variant of rout /raʊt, rut/ [verb] to bellow, roar [noun] a bellow. Origin: 1250-1300; Middle English rowten < Old Norse rauta to bellow; akin to Latin rudere (ablative singular of rūdus).

Therefore, some alternative sentences would be:

> - "You'll be getting standing ovations from me."
> - "I've got your back! Go get 'em!"
> - "I'll be there to support you."
> - "I'm cheering for you."

Answer (score 1):

Root for - phrasal verb - definitions from diferente sources:

> - [to show support for someone who is in a competition or who is doing something difficult.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/root-for-sb)
> - [to wish the success of or lend support to someone or something.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/root)
> - [take sides with; align oneself with; show strong sympathy for.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/root+for)
> - [to support someone in a game, competition, etc](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/root-for)
> - [Support or hope for the success of (a person or group entering a contest or undertaking a challenge)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/root-for?q=root+for)

Examples:

> “I’m sure you'll win. Everyone's rooting for you.”
>
> "We all rooted for the home team."
>
> "Most of the crowd were rooting for the home team."

As for your question, in addition to Thursagen's suggestions ("I'm supporting you", "I'll cheer for you" and "I'll barrack for you") and several others cited in the comments, I've found the following:

- I'm siding with you.
- I'm pulling for you.

In a sports context, however, "I'll cheer for you" and "I'm supporting you" sound like better choices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm keeping my fingers crossed that you will win.

Answer (score 1):

A little more casual way of saying it would be *"If I'm allowed to bet, I'll be betting for you."*

Answer (score 1):

You can use different expressions depending on the situation. Here are some of them:

- I am right behind you.
- You've got my vote.
- I'll be with you at every step.
- I'll be cheering for you.
- I'll be thinking of you.
- You are in my thoughts and prayers.

Look [here](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-phrase-Im-rooting-for-you-mean)  for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

How about,

> "I'm your biggest fan!"?

Answer (score 0):

- Break a leg!
- You go, girl!
- I’ve bet ten grand on youse guys.