# Answering a question using "I wish"

Tags: grammar

I was asked which team I would want to win a given game, so I answer something like:

> 1. I wish TEAM_A wins (the game).

However, it does not sound quite right to me, should I have rephrased the answer above to something like:

> 2. I wish TEAM_A to win.

What about when answering with I hope instead of I wish, should I use the same structrue of 1. or 2. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct usage in British English is:

Wish:

> I wish TEAM_A to win.

Hope:

> I hope TEAM_A wins (the game).

or

> I hope that TEAM_A wins (the game).

but for more idiomatic phrases see 
[Other ways to say "I'm rooting for you?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36745/other-ways-to-say-im-rooting-for-you)

A simple way to say it is "I'm supporting TEAM_A".

Comment: The only common variant in the UK in my opinion is "I hope City win". Notional agreement (plural verb-form in this case) is, in the UK, virtually universal here.